# Least squares why $||Ax-b||^2_2=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

Tags: self-learning, least-squares

Could someone explain the why the following equality holds?

I am trying to learn this subject alone, and haven't found a good resources to explain why the following is true?

$||Ax-b||^2_2=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$?

Comment: @JaVaPG Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$\vec x^T \vec x=\langle\vec x,\vec x\rangle=\sum x_i^2=\|\vec x\|^2$$